# How to use react-redux store with Async HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to update a div with a number using an AJAX call. Here's the widget:

```
import {store} from './Store';

class Widget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        let req = function() {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', this.props.apiUrl, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.response) {
                        store.dispatch({
                            type: 'SET_STATE',
                            state: {
                                foo: JSON.parse(xhr.response)
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }.bind(this);
            xhr.send();
        }
        req.call(this);
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <widget>
                <div>{this.props.foo}</div>
            </widget>
        );
    }
}
```

Heres the "reducer":

```
import {List, Map} from 'immutable';
export default function(state = Map(), action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SET_STATE':
            return state.merge(action.state);
    }
    return state;
}
```

And here's the store:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import reducer from '../reducer';

export const store = createStore(reducer);
```

When I run this code, I get the page to load, but `foo` is undefined. The request returns a response with the correct data. `dispatch()` is being called correctly. How do I trigger a state change asynchronously that propagates throughout the entire app?

**NOTE**

*Please, please, please* do not forward me to verbose abstract blog posts like [this](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) or [this](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html). I need an actual working example of code that triggers a state change using `store.dispatch()`. Thanks.

Comment: Are you not using `react-redux` ?

Comment: Once your reducer runs it should trigger and re-render, depending on how you are connecting the component.

Comment: My guess is this component is not `connect`ed

Comment: you're missing react-redux bindings http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: @azium I am importing `store` as a component. Please see the update

Comment: @tonylefler no im not lol. please see the example. Also, please dont just post a link that doesn't say something specific. I have no idea what I was supposed to get out of the link you posted.

Comment: @dopatraman That link has very specific instructions on what to do. I understand you may be frustrated by your problem, but the addition of `react-redux` is one of the first things you need to do if you you're using redux and react together. specifically read the section on Container Components

Comment: @dopatraman the first link you posted is not an abstract blog post. It's a thorough explanation of exactly what you're asking, written by the creator of redux. If you read it you will find out that you need to use redux-thunk or redux-promise.

Comment: @hansn OP doesn't need redux-thunk in this case. It may be a useful addition later on, but triggering the ajax call in a lifecycle method and dispatching there will work.

Comment: @azium can one of you post an example of how to do this?

Comment: @hanan can you post an example of how to do this?

Comment: @azium Oh. I wasn't aware of that :)

Comment: @dopatraman reading docs can sometimes be difficult, but it is an essential programming skill - the docs I posted explain everything you need to hook up react/redux the right way

Comment: lol i appreciate the advice @tonylefler, but reading skills notwithstanding redux seems to be an unnecessarily complex way of doing something very simple.

Answer (score 0):

As Azium mentioned in the comments, you don't need redux-thunk to do this, however this is how you would.

You apply redux-thunk middleware to your store:

```
var thunk = require('redux-thunk');
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        reducer1,
        reducer2
    }),
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Then you can define actions like this:

```
export const getData = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return fetch('/foo')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => dispatch(receieveData(json)));
    };
};
```

Where receieveData is another action that you have defined.

Now you could call this action in `componentWillMount`. I might have missed something, but that's the gist of it. It's all in the first link from your original post (http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html).

Edit: and of course, as many have said already, you need react-redux :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. I was not setting the initial state.

```
// Store.jsx

import {fromJS} from 'immutable';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import reducer from '../reducer';

export const store = createStore(reducer);
store.dispatch({
    type:'SET_STATE',
    state: fromJS({
        foo: 0
    })
})
```

Without this, the state being updated was always `null`. This simple fact was not in any of the official React/Redux documents.